# How to convert a file rss to xml in python?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, rss, format-conversion

I need to convert the page cnn rss (http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss) to XML file. I need to filter with the tag: title, link and pubDate and then export to csv file the result.

I am tried a code but not  work  because the result omit the pubDate.

I use this code:

```
# Python code to illustrate parsing of XML files
# importing the required modules
import csv
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
def loadRSS():
# url of rss feed
url = 'http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss'
# creating HTTP response object from given url
resp = requests.get(url)
# saving the xml file
with open('topnewsfeed.xml', 'wb') as f:
f.write(resp.content)
def parseXML(xmlfile):
# create element tree object
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
# get root element
root = tree.getroot()
# create empty list for news items
newsitems = []
# iterate news items
for item in root.findall('./channel/item'):
# empty news dictionary
news = {}
# append news dictionary to news items list
newsitems.append(news)
# return news items list
return newsitems
def savetoCSV(newsitems, filename):
# specifying the fields for csv file
fields = ['title', 'pubDate', 'description', 'link', 'media']
# writing to csv file
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:
# creating a csv dict writer object
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fields)
# writing headers (field names)
writer.writeheader()
# writing data rows
writer.writerows(newsitems)
def main():
# load rss from web to update existing xml file
loadRSS()
# parse xml file
newsitems = parseXML('topnewsfeed.xml')
# store news items in a csv file
savetoCSV(newsitems, 'topnews.csv')
if __name__ == "__main__":
# calling main function
main()
```

i tryed to configure the parameters and the result is this:

CNN show the rss as web format  not as xml, for example reddit:

- http://www.reddit.com/.rss
- http://rss.cnn.com/rss/edition.rss

any idea of how obtain this information?

Comment: Given the importance of indentation in python i think it would help a lot if you looked at the formatting of your post.

Answer (score 1):

The XML entry for the RSS feed you mentioned is `pubdate`, not `pubDate` with a capital D.

If the issue is that pubdate isn't being included, that might be part of the problem.

Comment: ok, this code have two parts, the first part save the xml and the second part work with this XML and create a CSV file with this information. in this moment i can create the xml but i have a error with create the CSV file.